# How to use autocorrelation function(xcorr2) to reveal periodic pattern in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, autocorrelation

[Revealing periodic patterns with autocorrelation function in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx1Qr.png)

[Example of periodic pattern embedded in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTcJ5.png)

Periodic patterns are embedded in upper 3 images at different angles. The autocorrelation function of these images yields the output as the lower three images.
I want to know how can I get this kind of output after autocorrelation of an image?

Comment: You mention `xcorr2`, I’m sure you’ve read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html). What is missing in your understanding to get this to work? Please [edit] your question to clarify. See [ask].

Comment: By the way, the first image you posted doesn’t show autocorrelation functions, don’t feel bad if you can’t reproduce those. I have no idea what that is, but they’re not autocorrelation functions. Note also the first and third image there are very similar, yet the function shown underneath is very different

Comment: @CrisLuengo What I want to know is that how autocorrelation function is used to reveal pattern(embedded in an image as watermark) from an image?